# Unable to find or load Qt platform plugin "xcb" on Debian stretch

Tags: debian, vlc, qt

I've been having a problem loading software that use xcb, such as vlc and plasma desktop. Vlc gives the following error:

> [0000000000ddc148] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
>
> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".
>
> Available platform plugins are: linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, wayland-egl, wayland.
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>
> Aborted

I have `libxcb1` and `libx11-xcb1` installed; reinstalling them and vlc didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On what system? From the tags I'm assuming you are running Debian?

On debian jessie and testing, the xcb plugin is in the `libqt5gui5` package, but `vlc` depends on it. On some older versions of qt5 packaging, the package containing the qpa plugin used to be `libqt5xcbqpa5`.

Comment: I'm using debian. Installing libqt5gui5 solved the problem! Thank you! I'm a bit ashamed that i didn't look through the dependencies before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Two years later, on Debian 9.3 Stretch I solved it installing the package `xcb-proto`. So I post this answer for other users.

I was unable to run some programs: LibreCAD, MEGAsync, VirtualBox... They have in common some dependencies: `libc6, libgcc1 libgl1 libqt5core5a libqt5widgets5 libstdc++6`

Answer (score 0):

Solved in Fedora 25 with the commands

```
ln -sf /usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/platforms/ /usr/bin/platforms
```

and

```
ldd /usr/bin/platforms/libqxcb.so | grep "not found"
```